# Attach more file on request with express-fileupload

Tags: express, file-upload, middleware, express-fileupload

We are using express-fileupload  to uploading file on express project. Currently with some special case we want to add more file into request with some url. We create a new middleware to attach new file into request.files but not success.

Comment: We have no idea why it doesn't work if you don't provide any relevant information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @robertklep
This is my source code of middleware file
HTML <img src="https://imgur.com/fsZaTPV">